# How to customize List of a location on a map

Tags: android

i make this class
to get list of a location on a map

```
public class ShowMapUtil {
    public static void showMap(Context context, Uri geoLocation) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(geoLocation);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

, but I would like to show customized view a list of "complete action using"

how to make...?

Comment: use own map view in application

Comment: um... i want to customize list  view of "complete action using"